# Calendar group by event in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have calendar inside that I have created an event which starts from march (01/03/2016) to ends on May(29/05/2016).

I have created a calculated field "Month" which fetch month as a number like 3 for march and 5 for May. Then created a view and used group by "month". I can see that event which is from march (03) to May(05) is falling under March category only. however it should fall under April and May too.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? is it SP2013 on-premises or SP online or is it SP 2010?

Comment: SP 2010 version

Comment: is my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using SharePoint 2010 then Recurring events will be stored
>   as a single item with a rule attached to show all recurrences in the
>   calendar view.
>
> **In your case, It is doing the same. That's why your event which is
>   from march (03) to May(05) is falling under March category only.**
>
> The only way to have individual events out of a recurring event is to
>   edit any single event in the calendar view and save them without
>   modification. This will generate single events out of the recurring
>   event.
>
> *The problem then is whenever you edit the series this events won't be part of the recurring event. The single events also won't be updated.*

Answer (score 0):

I just have had created calendar list and created additional column Month.
Month column formula is this

> =TEXT([Month column name],"m")

Than I created new View, regular/standard view and used Group by feature to group by month.

Comment: this is not working. The event start from march to May will still fall under only march group.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is working based on single selection not on multi selection.

And your scenario is something like one item grouped by March, April and May month. It is not possible.

You should create `recurrence event` with `monthly` category for specific date range. Open `Current Events` view from Calendar list. You can see recurrence items of each month.